# CMake project linking a static library

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, static-libraries

I'm currently trying to include a static library into my cmake project. When I build the project I get errors like this:

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/MainApp.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable MainApp
../../lib/librplidar_sdk.a(thread.o): In function `rp::hal::Thread::create(unsigned long (*)(void*), void*)':
thread.cpp:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/../lib/librplidar_sdk.a(thread.o): In function `rp::hal::Thread::terminate()':
thread.cpp:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `pthread_cancel'
```

The CMakeLists.txt looks like this (RPlidar beeing the static library):

```
##################################################################
#                          RPLidar SDK                           #
##################################################################
add_library(RPlidar STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET RPlidar PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/librplidar_sdk.a)
set_property(TARGET RPlidar APPEND PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/rplidar>
)

##################################################################
#                         Main Executable                        #
##################################################################
add_executable(MainApp main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MainApp PRIVATE RPlidar)
```

I found out that those kind of errors appear when the linker option (-l) is placed in FRONT of the name of the file to be compiled and not AFTER it. But I have no idea how to resolve this in my cmake configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to link `pthread`:

```
target_link_libraries(MainApp PRIVATE pthread RPlidar)
```

Comment: Better yet: `find_package(Threads REQUIRED)` and then link to `Threads::Threads`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I actually used INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES now so I dont have to specify Threads::Threads every time i use this target.